# How do I activate my inactive datastore on the command line?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

Have two volumes on a datastore on ESXi 5.1.  On the GUI, one shows up greyed out and the word "(inactive)".  The other doesn't show in the GUI at all.

However, on the commandline:

```
~ # esxcli storage nfs list
Volume Name  Host            Share                      Accessible  Mounted  Read-Only  Hardware Acceleration
-----------  --------------  -------------------------  ----------  -------  ---------  ---------------------
volume1      10.200.201.140  /export1                   true        true     false      Supported            
volume2      10.200.201.140  /export1/somedir           true        true     false      Supported
```

Is there a way to detect this on the command line?  More importantly, is there a way to "re-activate" them?

EDIT:
I cannot make a comment nor answer my own question.  :-(

Anyway, I ended up doing something like this (for each volume):

```
#!/bin/sh
while [[ 1 ]]; do
    echo "$(df -h)" | grep -q "/vmfs/volumes/volume1$"
    volume1_mounted=$?
    if [[ $volume1_mounted -ne 0 ]]; then
       esxcli storage nfs add -H 10.200.201.140 -s /share1 -v volume1
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
esxcfg-nas -r
```

to remount NAS filesystems on ESXi. See the command syntax:

```
esxcfg-nas <options> [<label>]
-a|--add                Add a new NAS filesystem to /vmfs volumes.  
                        Requires --host and --share options.
                        Use --readonly option only for readonly access.
-o|--host <host>        Set the host name or ip address for a NAS mount.
-s|--share <share>      Set the name of the NAS share on the remote system.
-y|--readonly           Add the new NAS filesystem with readonly access.
-d|--delete             Unmount and delete a filesystem.
-l|--list               List the currently mounted NAS file systems.
-r|--restore            Restore all NAS mounts from the configuration file. 
                        (FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY).
-h|--help               Show this message.
```

Comment: Great suggestion, except, as far as I can tell, it makes no difference.  I found a cheezy hack that I'll use until I can resolve this long term, see my answer to my question.

Comment: Hmm... okay. Good luck!